# "Sidebar icon size" option disabling for NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pxsourcelist

I'm using [PXSourceList](https://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList) (NSOutlineView subclass) for my OSX project and want to disable "Sidebar icon size" (System Preferences -> General) option for my App. I'd like my icons always be small.

P.S. PXSourceList is in view-based mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Cell-Based views are still used in general as that's when the preferences apply to the image size of the nodes.

Also I just saw that PXSourceList also note this in their API Doc:

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/PXSourceList/2.0.1/Classes/PXSourceList.html